# R Reshape Dataframe from Long to Wide

Tags: r, dataframe, reshape

```
Station_list =  rep(c("ABC", "DEF", "GHI", "JKL", "MNO", "PQR"), each = 61)
testframe = data.frame(Station = Station_list)
testframe$Value = seq(from = 10, to = 25, length.out = 366)
testframe$Date = seq(ymd('2000-01-01'),ymd('2000-12-31'),by='day')
```

I want to reshape this dataframe into this format:

```
Date          Station_ABC   Station_DEF   Station_GHI    Station_JKL    Station_MNO   Station_PQR 
2000-01-01    correct_values
```

I tried to reshape my dataframe in many different ways, but nothing worked how I wanted it.

```
library(reshape)
test <- cast(testframe, Date + Value ~ Station)

library(furniture)
test = wide (testframe, v.names = "Station", timevar = "Date", id = "Value")
test = wide (testframe, v.names = NULL, timevar = "Station", id = c("Value", "Date"))

test = reshape(testframe, v.names="Station", timevar="Date", idvar=c("Value"), direction="wide")
```

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Did you try `tidyr::spread(testframe, Station, Value)` or `pivot_wider` in the newer `tidyr`.

Comment: Thanks! That is working!